# VB.Net MVC DropdownFor on Edit page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to populate a dropdown list in an edit view and return the 'id' (new_groupid) back to the controller. I'm using VB.net and cannot seem to convert and adapt any of the c examples to my project.
Calling Function

```
Function Edit(ByVal id As Guid?) As ActionResult
If IsNothing(id) Then
    Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
End If
Dim new_accountsdata As new_accountsdata = db.new_accountsdata.FirstOrDefault(Function(ac) ac.new_accountsdataId = id)
If IsNothing(new_accountsdata) Then
    Return HttpNotFound()
End If

Dim LicenceGuid = New Guid(_selectedLicenceID)
Dim GroupList = db.new_bankinggroups.Where(Function(bg) bg.new_licenceid = LicenceGuid And bg.statecode = 1).ToList

Return View(new_accountsdata)
```

End Function

Return

```
        Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="new_accountsdataId, new_sortcode,new_accountname,new_accountnumber,new_accountreference, new_defaultvalue,new_groupid")> ByVal new_accountsdata As new_accountsdata) As ActionResult
```

View (Section )  I only need one dropdownfor box for the selection on the group name

```
   <div class="form-group">
   @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.new_groupidName, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
   <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.new_groupidName, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})
   </div>
```

@Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.new_groupid, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
       
           @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.new_groupid, New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.class = "form-control"}})